# Selecting and moving multiple files at a time

Tags: user-experience

Want to search for "Lorem Ipsum.sql" type of files within the uploaded 1000 different .sql files. Now user has to move some of these files(can be multiple of 100) user should able to select all the files from search result like `Lor`em Ipsum, `Lorem` Ipsum or `Lorem Ipsum` and move them at a time.
Is it possible? If yes then how? what control should i give to the user at interface level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the same UX as the one implemented in Gmail.

Here's the experience:

- Try typing a search within your mails, and then check the upper-left checkbox. All your results get selected.
- Now click *Inbox* button and you will see all of your mails, the only one selected will be those appearing in your previous search results.

You could implement something like this for your search by providing actions for all selected mails, such as Gmail features.